# Controlling a LDO with voltage detector

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, batteries, low-battery

For one of my project I need to shutdown my system when my Li-ion battery reaches 3V.
But I want to know if I can use this type of component : http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/11601.pdf
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/76549.pdf
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/11603.pdf
For detecting the battery voltage and disabling my LDO? I know they are designed to be used for the Reset of microcontrollers.
But it should work just fine by using one of those three no?
Thank you in advance !
**EDIT :**
I first wanted to use the TC54 from Microchip which is designed for this purpose but it seems to be obsolete...
I also need the system to be through hole.. This is why I don't use a battery protection chip, because I could not find one..

Comment: Yes, I guess that would work. **But** why do you want to disable the LDO when Vbat becomes less than 3 V. Because you do not want to drain the battery more and damage it, right ? So why not use a **battery protection chip** instead ? The parts you suggest continously draw a small current which will still very slowly drain the battery instead of disconnecting the battery completely (which is what protection ICs do).

Comment: @FakeMoustache thank you for your response. I know I need a  **battery protection chip**, but I could not find one in **through hole** configuration... So I came up with this trick. If you know a reference let me know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a combined charge and discharge protector like this: -

[image]

This might be more of an effective solution. If you just want a low discharge current solution that is available in through-hole components then this might be of interest: -

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54493/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-controlling-a-ldo-with-voltage-detector).

Answer (score 0):

Using an ADC on a small micro controller would be an easy way to check and control things depending on the voltage of your battery, no complicated electronics.

Comment: Using a microcontroller here would be overkill ! But thanks ;)

Comment: Even an Attiny? It is by far the simplest.

Comment: It's not very power efficient to use a microcontroller in my case. I only have a LDO on the board. I am going to use the TC54VC3002EZB, see comments above. :)

Comment: Fair enough reasons.