# Li-po battery protection

Tags: lipo

I have got schema of li-po battery protection circuit.[image: here]

translation of czech title of components:
Napěťová reference = voltage reference
Zátěž = output of protection circuit

Battery has got 2.75v cut-off voltage, i want to have reserve.
But I do not know what component should I use, so can I use these:
voltage reference = MCP1501T-10E/CHY. 
comparator = AS393P-E1
transistor = BS250P-DIC
Can someone help me?

Comment: Just change the divider to the desired threshold.

Comment: Don't use that at all. There's ready to buy, low component count (down to exactly 1 component) and cheaper dedicated liIon protection ICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but your schematic will not work this way:

- The AS393P-E1 is a *comparator*. That means it has an open collector/drain output. You need to have a pull-up resistor at the output, otherwise the gate of your transistor will be floating when the output of the comparator is high. Not good.
- The Gate-Source Threshold Voltage of the BS250P-DIC is max. -3.5V@Id=-1mA. So even applying the full battery voltage of 3.6V to the gate isn't going to be enough to power your load properly.
- The voltage divider is slowly draining your battery (12uA).

What do you mean with 'I want to have reserve'? Is this an additional circuit, after the circuit that's built into the battery? If not, and this is the only protection circuit, go with the suggestion of @Marcus. Then please be careful: Li-Po batteries can really explode or burn when not handled properly!

---

Edit:

Ok, I promised you a 'keep it simple' answer. Here's a schematic, based upon the schematic you posted.
[image: Improved schematic]
I used the MCP1501T-10E/CHY you suggested. It outputs 1.024V. The 1.69M/1M voltage divider outputs 1.024V when the battery is at 2.755V. I also added pullup resistor R4, to force Q1 OFF when the battery voltage is too low. I kept the comparator you suggested. Please note that the Source and Drain of the transistor in your schematic were wrong as well. I only saw that just now. So make sure you wire the transistor the correct way, as in my schematic.

Now, there are a few problems:

- I couldn't find a P-channel enhancement MOSFET (Transistor Q1), that has a low enough Gate Threshold Voltage at the required 75mA. Maybe someone else on this website knows one? Problem is also that I don't know *where* you're 'shopping' for one. But I don't want to invest any more time in searching. I'm sorry.
- This circuit consumes power, as I already mentioned. Problem is that it *continues* to consume power when the battery is near empty. So that's not a very good protection I guess. It consumes about 1uA for the voltage divider + 140uA for the voltage reference + 600uA for the comparator = 741uA. It's not super much, but enough to *completely* drain you battery in time. So be careful there.

Also take a look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289140/controlling-a-ldo-with-voltage-detector). It has some really good solutions, that might be much better then the schematic I've posted. Especially the 'yellow' schematic seems like something you might fancy.

Looking at your comments, I got the impression that you wanted a schematic similar to what you posted, so I hope this helps.

---

Update:

This is the new schematic.
[image: New schematic]

As you can see, I did NOT use the TL431, as it has a *minimum* output current of 1mA, which is way too much for your purpose. So that will not work. I used a LM385Z-1.2G instead, which has a minimum output current of 10-20uA - way better. It outputs a voltage of 1.235V

So how to calculate the resistors?

- R9 needs to make sure that the minimum current is 20uA. Let's say we want the regulator to work upto 2.235V. That's 1V dropout (2.235-1.235=1V). R=U/I, so R=1V/20uA = 50k. 50k is a hard-to-find value, as resistors go in E-ranges. 47k is in the E6 range, so very easy to find. (The higher the E number, the higher the precision (lower tolerance), and the harder it gets to find + more expensive).
- E6 means there are 6 values per decade (6 values for 0-9, 6 for 10-99, 6 for 100-999, ...)
- E12 means there are 12 values per decade
- [You have E6, E12, E24, E48, E96, E192](http://logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html)

R5 / R6:

This is a voltage divider. The input current of the opamp is very low, so we can leave that out for simplicity.

1. The voltage Vout = Vin * R6/(R5+R6). You can even use an [online calculator](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator).
2. Vin is the Voltage at which you want to switch off your battery: 3V
3. Vout is the voltage of your voltage reference: 1.235V
4. You assume one resistor, and calculate the other. The current that will flow is I=U/R =Vbat/(R5+R6), so you don't want the resistors too small, as the power consumption will be too high. You also don't want them too large, as your schematic will be more subject to interference. Probably R5+R6 somewhere between 500K and 2M will be fine.
5. Let's assume R6 (use a value from E12 or E24). That gives you a value for R5. Find the value closest in E12 or E24, and calculate the dropout Voltate Vin again with the right resistor values. Go to step 4, and repeat, until you find a good combination that comes close enough to what you want. Use values from E12 or E24, as they are usually easy to find.

I found a good combination for R5=1M, and R6=680k. That gives you a cutoff Voltage of 3.051V - close enough. Another option would be R5=1.5M and R6=1M. That gives a cutoff of 3.088V, also close enough I think. With 2.5M total resistance, your power consumption would be less, but both are negligible compared to the power usage of your comparator anyway. The 2.5M option would give a bit more chance of interference, so I picked the lower option.

The process of 'assuming' one resistor to calculate the other is a bit hard in the beginning, but as you use components more, and learn the E values by heart, it gets easier. Capacitors and the like also use E ranges, so you'll use them a lot!

Good luck!

Comment: Nice one! Really got all it takes!

Comment: My battery doesn't have a protection circuit. On the eshop, where I am shopping, They don't have a li-po protection circuit. Can you help me with editing circuit for work on this bettery, Thanks

Comment: What is the capacity of your battery? How much current do you want to be able to draw from it? How are you planning to charge your battery? Do you need overcurrent and overvoltage protection as well? (My opinion is that protection of Li-Po batteries is about more than just undervoltage.) Depending on your answers, we could redesign your initial schematic (and thus keep it simple), but I'm not certain if that will be 'safe' enough or if it will be satisfactory to your demands.

Comment: Also, check out [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295181/designing-under-over-voltage-lipo-protection-circuit)

Comment: Capacity is 300 mAh, max current will be 75 mA. For charging I have circuit on board, it has over-voltage and over-current protection. Low safety doesn't matter.

Comment: But i don't now how to edit it.

Comment: Now for the ones reading along: Doing the math, I found the schematic consumes 741uA. It's a total coincidence, but that number combined with the uA sounds so familiar... ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will use it in atmega328 powered watches, so i will charge them daily, so 741 uA doesn't matter. I am shopping on tme.eu, but they don't have 1.69 M resistor, have I to use bigger or smaller? The output of circuit is R4?

Comment: Use R5=560k and R6=330k. This will give you 2.76V cut-off. The output is NOT R4, it's R_load! Make sure you remove R_load, and replace it with whatever you want to power.

Comment: For your transistor Q1, you can use [LP0701N3-G](https://www.tme.eu/nl/Document/8454564d4068e40cdea457c6f0f143a9/lp0701.pdf). They have it at your shop, it has good specs for what you want to do with it, and it's in TO-92 package, which is easy to solder.

Comment: Last question, then I will mark this thread as solved. Is U3.2 needed?

Comment: The AS393P you are using, has *two* comparators inside. So two in one chip. You're only using one of them, so the other one is just sitting there unused. Look at the pin numbers. Pin 1,2,3 belong to the first comparator, and pin 5,6,7 to the second. Because you're not using the second comparator, it's good practise to ground the unused inputs. And that's why I drew the schematic that way - to make sure you connect pin 5 and 6 to GND. Pin 7 can be left floating, since it's an output. So you only need to buy *one* chip.

Comment: I ordered voltage reference, but it's SMD and it's to small for soldering :-(. So I will return it (In Czech republic we have 14 days for returning goodies ordered by Internet :-) ). I will order [TL431CLPE3](https://www.tme.eu/cz/details/tl431clpe3/zdroje-napetove-reference-obvody/texas-instruments/). I want higher cut-off voltage - 3v. Can you help me with R5+R6?

Comment: I already wondered about the SMD voltage reference, but as it also comes in a SOIC - which is not *that* small, I thought it would be ok. I posted an updated schematic. I did NOT use the TL431, as it is unfit for your application (see my updated post)